# How many strictly increasing functions can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Let $A=\{x \in\mathbb{N}~|~x\leq10\}$, $B=\{x \in\mathbb{N}~|~x\leq100\}$

$f: A \longrightarrow B$

How many strictly increasing functions can be made?

I thought: I have $91$ options for $f(1)$ (must be within $1$ and $91$, else some $f(x)$ next to this one would be left without image).

Then $91-f(1)$ options for $f(2)$

$91-f(2)$ for $f(3)$

$91-f(3)$ for $f(4)$ ...

Until $91-f(9)$ options for $f(10)$

So my total number of options would be $(91)(91-f(1))(91-f(2))...(91-f(9))$?

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: No, this makes no sense, because your final answer is not a number: it contains  $f(1), f(2), \ldots$.

Comment: But $f(1),f(2)$ are numbers, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, they are. So, evaluate that expression, and tell us what you get (this is to help you see what's wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I'm afraid it is not. What is "$(91)(91 - f(1)) \cdots (91 - f(9))$" even supposed to mean if you don't know what $f$ is? The answer to this question should be simply a number.

A little hint: What you're actually looking for is the number of ways of picking $10$ values out of $100$ without considering their order.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong. Why 9 numbers tho?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Oops, I read $<$ instead of $\leq$. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give a little more insight? I think I understand this but I'm not completely sure. This topic is a bit hard for me.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: So, a strictly increasing function $f$ could be for example $f(1) = 3, f(2) = 17, f(3) =20, \dots$. We could simply write $\{ 3, 17, 20, \dots \}$ instead: Specifying the set of values, 10 different natural numbers less or equal $100$, is enough information to know $f$. Crucially, the order does not matter: The lowest of the numbers will be $f(1)$, the second lowest is $f(2)$ and so on.

Hence it all comes down to pick an (unordered) set of 10 different values out of the list of 100 possible numbers. You should know that there are $\binom{100}{10}$ possibilities to do that.